# Extract an array from a collection

Tags: arrays, swift

I get an element from a collection with this code:

```
modelCollec[indexPath].model
```

I want to get all models in an array. Is there a function or shall I write a loop?

There is only one row so indexPath is always `[0, index]`.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`flatMap`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1689578-flatmap) for that.

```
let modelArray = modelCollec.flatMap { $0.model }
```

modelArray type is `[model]`.

### For eg:

```
struct Person {
    var name: String
}
```

Now if you have array of `person` and you want array of `name` from it you can get it using `flatMap` like this way.

```
let persons = [Person]()
let nameArray = persons.flatMap { $0.name } //nameArray type is [String]
```

**Note:** You can also use [`map`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1688519-map) instead of `flatMap` but it will give you optional objects if your model property is optional so it may contains `nil` where as `flatMap` ignore the `nil` object.

Comment: There is no need to use `flatMap` (unless `model` is an optional property). `map` is sufficient, see the "duplicate".

Comment: @MartinR Edited answer for that :)

Answer (score 1):

If you always want to access the 1st element of the collection then it is a better idea to hardcode the 0 index rather than using loop, however to it is always better to put a check for nil.